# ArrayDeque isn't empty but returns null for the poll method

Tags: java, queue

I have this code (Obfuscated) as part of a large application and it's getting a `NullPointerException` on the `object.doSomething()` line. Since we just checked the `isEmpty()` call and there is no other thread polling this queue, how is this possible? There are other threads adding to the queue; is it possible concurrent adds permanently screwed up the queue?

I tried reading the source code of `ArrayDeque` and it uses `head == tail` as a check for `isEmpty()`. Is it possible some weird collision during adds made `head != tail` but the `head` point to `null`?

```
private final Queue<Task> active = new ArrayDeque<Task>();
if (!this.active.isEmpty()) {
    SomeType object = null;
    object = this.active.poll();
    object.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if there is no other thread polling, there are probably other threads pushing.

This means in a concurrent access that tail can be modified incorrectly, and if tail is corrupted you may never get to the point where `head == tail`, hence the `NullPointerException`.

As @dacwe stated, the documentation clearly specify that you (or the developers of this obfuscated application) should not use `ArrayDeque` in a concurrent environment, this is one of the possible problems with concurrency.

---

> **They are not thread-safe**; in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads.

---

If you want a threadsafe [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) you can use [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html), if you need a [`Dequeue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) you can use [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html).

---

**Resources:**

- [Javadoc: ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html):

> They are **not thread-safe;** in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads.

Comment: I think that OP already knows that, he just wants to know why a simple check on `head == tail` can fail. It's more an explanation that is required here than a quote from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the case when `active.poll()` accesses the old elements[] reclaimed in `ArrayDequeue.doubleCapacity()` for which the deque is full at the same time.

One possible timeline:

1. The polling thread checks out `active.isEmpty()` returns false
2. The polling thread calls ```active.pollFirst() to access the elements[] which is not atomic
3. One or more other threads call `active.addLast()` in bursts so that `active` is full and doubleCapacity() is triggered
4. In doubleCapacity(), the elements[] is replaced with a newly allocated array such that the old elements[] is reclaimed by GC
5. The polling thread now references the reclaimed elements[] and possibly gets null.

My guess is that you would like to avoid synchronization for polling while the queue is not empty. To avoid the race due to doubleCapacity(), make sure the queue is allocated with a sufficiently large capacity and will not be full anytime addLast() is called. However, there might be other races you need to consider depending on the actual implementation.

The following sources from openJDK are appended FYI.

```
public E pollFirst() {
    int h = head;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    E result = (E) elements[h];
    // Element is null if deque empty
    if (result == null)
        return null;
    elements[h] = null;     // Must null out slot
    head = (h + 1) & (elements.length - 1);
    return result;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[tail] = e;
    if ( (tail = (tail + 1) & (elements.length - 1)) == head)
        doubleCapacity();
}

private void doubleCapacity() {
    assert head == tail;
    int p = head;
    int n = elements.length;
    int r = n - p; // number of elements to the right of p
    int newCapacity = n << 1;
    if (newCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Sorry, deque too big");
    Object[] a = new Object[newCapacity];
    System.arraycopy(elements, p, a, 0, r);
    System.arraycopy(elements, 0, a, r, p);
    elements = a;
    head = 0;
    tail = n;
}
```